# Pandas Sum Diagonal Value with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to sum the diagonal value of each year and residue, grouping by Object. For example for object a will be 1 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13. Is there any way to do it without splitting the table by object? Note that the number of rows might be different for each object. I have tried:
df.groupby('Company').apply(lambda x: x.reset_index().loc[0,'Year_0']+x.reset_index().loc[1,'Year_1']+ x.reset_index().loc[2,'Year_2']+x.reset_index().loc[3,'Year_3']) but it requires defined number of rows. Thanks!

---

```
Year_0  Year_1  Year_2  Year_3  Residue Company
1       0.0     0.0     0.0      10      a
1       10      0.0     0.0      10      a
1       10       11     0.0      10      a
1       10       11      12      13      a
2       0      0.0      0.0      12      b
2       11     0.0      0.0      12      b
2       11      12      0.0      12      b
2       11      12       13      12      b
-3     0       0.0      0.0      -1      c
-3     -1       0.0     0.0      -1      c
-3     -2       -3      0.0      -1      c
```

Comment: try `groupby` company followed with `trace`

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), create index by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), `sum` rows and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates('Company', keep='last')
         .set_index('Company')
         .sum(axis=1)
         .reset_index(name='new'))
print (df1)
  Company   new
0       a  47.0
1       b  50.0
2       c  -9.0
```

Or use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby('Company', as_index=False).last()
       .set_index('Company')
       .sum(axis=1)
       .reset_index(name='new'))
```

If want working with diagonal values use [`numpy.diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html):

```
s = df.drop_duplicates('Company', keep='last').set_index('Company')['Residue']

df = (df.drop('Residue', axis=1)
      .set_index('Company')
      .groupby('Company')
      .apply(lambda x: x.values.diagonal().sum())
      .add(s)
      .reset_index(name='new'))
print (df)
  Company   new
0       a  47.0
1       b  50.0
2       c  -8.0
```

Last value is `-8`, because `-3 + -1 + -3 + -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `groupby`:

```
print(df.groupby('Company',as_index=False).tail(1)
          .set_index('Company')
          .sum(axis=1)
          .reset_index(name='new'))
```

Output:

```
  Company   new
0       a  47.0
1       b  50.0
2       c  -9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

using `numpy` and `pandas groupby`

```
df.groupby('Company').apply(lambda x: np.sum(np.ma.diag(x.values)) + x.values[-1][-2])
```

Output

```
Company
a    47.0
b    50.0
c    -8.0
dtype: float64
```